# Does every partition of n correspond to some permutation of [1,2, ... n]?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

It is known that every permutation can be decomposed into disjoint cycles. The cycle type gives the length of each cycle. The sum of cycles length is n. I am wondering whether every partition of n corresponds to (cyclic decomposition) of a permutation of [1,2, ... n].

> Does every partition of n correspond to some permutation of [1,2, ... n]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you could map the partitions of $n$ into the set of permutations in $\mathcal{S}_n$.

If the partition is $j_1 + \dots + j_k = n$ where $j_1 \geq \dots \geq j_k$, then we can map it uniquely to the permutation $(1 \dots j_1) (j_1 + 1 \dots j_1 + j_2) \dots (n-j_k+1 \dots n)$

For example, with $n = 5$ and the permutation $2 + 2 + 1 = 5$, we can map it to $(12)(34)(5)$.

This map is injective but not surjective (of course, not surjective since the number of partitions is less than $n!$).

The motivation behind this is that each permutation has a cycle type which corresponds very naturally to a partition. We are taking the opposite direction with this map: we take a certain cycle type defined by a partition and map it to one specific permutation with the cycle type.

Comment: Do you have  a book that proves this fact please "If the partition is $j_1 + \dots + j_k = n$ where $j_1 \geq \dots \geq j_k$, then we can map it uniquely to the permutation $(1 \dots j_1) (j_1 + 1 \dots j_1 + j_2) \dots (n-j_k+1 \dots n)$"?

Comment: @Math No book in mind. The statement is pretty feasible to prove as an exercise, in my opinion. Show that if you have two different partitions, you get a different permutation, thus the map is injective.