# How can we map a partition of $n$ to some permutation of [1,2, ... , n]?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, permutations, symmetric-groups, integer-partitions

Here is the question I was reading:

[Does every partition of n correspond to some permutation of [1,2, ... n]?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1766316/does-every-partition-of-n-correspond-to-some-permutation-of-1-2-n)

And here is a statement in the answer given there that I want to use:

If the partition is $j_1 + \dots + j_k = n$ where $j_1 \geq \dots \geq j_k$, then we can map it uniquely to the permutation $(1 \dots j_1) (j_1 + 1 \dots j_1 + j_2) \dots (n-j_k+1 \dots n)$

**My question is:**

I want a reference (including specifically which edition)that contains this statement and its proof, could anyone help me in this please?

**EDIT:**

1-My question is why is this function unique? could not we define a different function? or unique here means well defined?

2- Also, how to prove that this function is well defined?

Comment: Seems too obvious for a reference. You don't need a proof the map exists; the map is already given to you!

Comment: Yeah I know the map exists .... but I need more information about that map ..... I also need to add the reference that contains that important information to my library @runway44

Comment: @MathIgnorance, Can you add few numerical examples for say $n=12$, $k=3, 4,5$?

Comment: @cosmo5 the link contains numerical example for $n=5,$ I am not sure why you want those specific numbers exactly?

Comment: What do you mean by asking if the map is unique/well-defined?  It's well-defined because the resulting permutation only depends on $j_1, j_2, \ldots, j_n$, and no  other choices. And it's not unique as a mapping from the set of permutations to the set of partitions.  For any two sets $A$ of size $m$ and $B$ of size $n$ there are $n^m$ mappings $A \rightarrow B$. That is, there are a lot of possible mappings.

Comment: @JairTaylor in the answer in the link I mentioned the author wrote that it is a unique map

Comment: @MathIgnorance Perhaps the use of the word 'unique' here is a little unclear.  Looking at that answer, I think the author meant that the map is well-defined in the sense that for this particular map, each permutation maps to only one partition. i.e., it is a function. It's also injective, which means that no two permutations map to the same partition

Comment: What I mean when I say it's not unique is that there are other functions that map permutations to partitions. For example, we can just reverse the order of the cycles to get another possible mapping.

Comment: @JairTaylor do you know the intuition behind defining this map? How the author thought about it?